# Paperclip S3 Heroku - missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use Paperclip and SWS S3 on Heroku to let users upload images.

I follow [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) and what I have when create new user

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#create

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

i have a no idea with it

users_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to bequem!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<%= provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>


<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :avatar %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
-->
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>


</div>
```

paperclip config on production and development

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['xxx'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['xxx'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['xxx']
  }
}
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # This method associates the attribute ":avatar" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar
```

papertrail log

```
Started GET "/signup" for 176.226.131.101 at 2014-01-20 17:45:54 +0000 
Jan 20 09:45:55 milker app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#new as HTML 
Jan 20 09:45:55 milker app/web.1:    Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms) 
Jan 20 09:45:55 milker app/web.1:    Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (164.7ms) 
Jan 20 09:45:55 milker app/web.1:    Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms) 
Jan 20 09:45:55 milker app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 199ms (Views: 168.1ms | ActiveRecord: 15.3ms) 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Started POST "/users" for 176.226.131.101 at 2014-01-20 17:46:11 +0000 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Processing by UsersController#create as HTML 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5KZg5kTVOWKN/VBFlw6BC5pJe1EGCBYtVN5zBXLXNT4=", "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f4f673ad6b8 @original_filename="3adPUTPPeg8.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"3adPUTPPeg8.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140120-2-n87ap6>>, "name"=>"slasher", "email"=>"slava.proshechkin@softeica.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"} 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Command :: convert '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc112820140120-2-k3pl9m' 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc112820140120-2-k3pl9m' 
Jan 20 09:46:11 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: convert '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "200x" -crop "200x200+0+33" +repage '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc112820140120-2-1acel98' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc112820140120-2-1acel98' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: convert '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc1128.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc112820140120-2-1fz8qbp' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/3adPUTPPeg820140120-2-yc112820140120-2-1fz8qbp' 
Jan 20 09:46:12 milker app/web.1:  [paperclip] saving /users/avatars/000/000/007/original/3adPUTPPeg8.jpg 
Jan 20 09:46:13 milker heroku/router:  at=info method=POST path=/users host=milker.herokuapp.com request_id=97266e1a-098b-4676-9ad2-791e85d25f43 fwd="176.226.131.101" dyno=web.1 connect=14ms service=2457ms status=500 bytes=643 
Jan 20 09:46:13 milker app/web.1:  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1653ms 
Jan 20 09:46:13 milker app/web.1:  ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option): 
Jan 20 09:46:13 milker app/web.1:    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

Any ideas?
thank you in advance

Comment: You should add some more info, like what have you tried so far, where it fails...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to manojild's answer, here's what you need to do (we've had this problem before):

---

**Model**

Don't know why, but you've got to include the `:bucket` option in your `Paperclip` model:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
                :default_url => "************",
                :storage => :s3,
                :bucket => 'bucket_name',
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS (we set this in an initializer)
```

---

**ENV Vars**

You're using `ENV` vars in your `development.rb`

Unless you've actually set these `VAR`s in your operating environment, you won't be able to access them. I'd recommend using the [`Figaro` gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to handle ENV vars in development & production, keeping consistency

Really you want your ENV vars to be like this:

```
:bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
:secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

You have them with the actual content inside currently

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it.

You wrote (we set this in an initializer).

It means that I must write 

`:s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['xxx'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['xxx'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['xxx']
  }`
in initializer/paperclip.rb ?

Comment: If you're going to use an initializer, you would use the "naked" data (not ENV vars) (your code is correct syntax). But if you want to use ENV vars, install the Figaro gem - makes it 100% simpler

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
:bucket => ENV['BEQUEM'],
:access_key_id => ENV['AKredacted'],
:secret_access_key => ENV['AKredacted']
```

Follow the tutorial exactly. It asks you to add:

```
:bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
:secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

These are environmental variables, and will be set using the `heroku config` command. You have replaced these with the actual values ( and potentially causing a security issue by exposing them here in public)

As mentioned in the tutorial, run these commands from you console:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
```

Don't forget to replace `your_bucket_name` etc with the actual value here :)

Comment: O thanks. I think I misunderstood this point of tutorial.

I made ​​the changes in paperclip config but I have same error on development and I can't deploy on heroku unfortunately

Comment: @V.Prosh - You have to set those environment variables in your terminal if you want this for development. Like `S3_BUCKET_NAME='bucket' bundle exec rails s`

Comment: ОК I'll try it.I set heroku config from console and fix production.rb as you said and here is log

`Jan 20 18:59:33 milker app/web.1: [paperclip] saving /users/avatars/000/000/010/original/0CE27BAE971DF6494F20441D62DFC0D1_1100_550.JPEG 
Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2787ms 
Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError ( 
Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: Missing Credentials. 
Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: Unable to find AWS credentials. You can configure your AWS credentials` And same error in create method

Answer (score 0):

Working user model. Plan to use Fedora in the future.

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => '60x60#', :large => '300x300#' }, :default_style => :large,
  :storage => :s3,
  :default_url => '/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png',
  :path => "users/:id/avatar/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => "bequem",
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => "xxx",
    :secret_access_key => "xxx"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application.rb file inside the module and class:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.before_configuration do
    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
    YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
        ENV[key.to_s] = value
    end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```